# Read kalima while washing hands

Tags: practical-islam

When our hands are not pak (dirty) for example after getting out of the washroom we wash hands and while washing read kalima three times. So is it necessary or not?

> kalima: (The Six Kalimah, also known as the Six Traditions or the Six
> Phrases, are six Islamic phrases often recited by South Asian
> Muslims.)

Comment: What exactly is "Kalma"?

Comment: The first kalima ( کلمہ)

Comment: And what is it? Urdu is not a standard language with standard terms on Islam. كلمة in Arabic means word. And this certainly is ambiguous.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Kalma or Kalima is Urdu for an Islamic oath/statement/declaration of allegiance with Allah.

Comment: @Epistemophile.Bibliophile then this is even more a reason to use to share the correct word(s) or include what exactly he means: shahadah: Ahshadu an-Laa Ilaaha Illa Allah ... whatever the wording would be good to know. But basically whatever you do in this situation is part of the sunnah it is not obligatory, but highly recommended unless there are reasons for a prohibition.